# How to compute Date and time to next Ascension / Descension of the Moon

Tags: the-moon

Is there an easy way to calculate the next date and time for Ascension / Descension of the Moon?

I work with swift language but a mock code will be ok for me.

Comment: Are you looking for a package, or an algorithm?  There is a package https://github.com/onekiloparsec/SwiftAA that provides [passageThroughAscendingNode()](https://onekiloparsec.dev/SwiftAA/Classes/Moon.html#/s:7SwiftAA4MoonC27passageThroughAscendingNodeAA9JulianDayVyF) That will be more accurate than any simple formula.

Comment: I will look at that it can be THE solution. thank you

Answer (score 2):

To do this accurately the algorithms are quite complex and most people will turn to a package to make sure that they aren't doing it wrong.

I found [SwiftAA](https://github.com/onekiloparsec/SwiftAA), which claims to be an implementation of the Meeus algorithms, and it contains a function for finding the date of nodes.

Alternatively, and for a "rough and ready" answer, you can use the fact that the mean time between ascendant nodes is 27.21222 days.  Just count days from a known node.

Or you can implement a simple look-up table from [list of all the nodes of the twentieth centruy](http://astropixels.com/ephemeris/moon/moonnodes2001.html) Which is accurate, but limited.